# Using Roslyn to load several projects

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am using Roslyn to display the C# projects that reference a given assembly by using the following code:

```
private static void ProcessProject(string projectName, string referenceName)
    {
        try
        {

            IWorkspace workspace = Workspace.LoadStandAloneProject(projectName);
            ISolution solution = workspace.CurrentSolution;

            string upper = referenceName.ToUpper();

            foreach (IProject project in solution.Projects)
            {
                IEnumerable<MetadataReference> metadataReferences = project.MetadataReferences;
                foreach (MetadataReference metadataReference in metadataReferences)
                {
                    if (metadataReference.Display.ToUpper().Contains(upper))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(project.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the memory is growing up (as I have hundreds of projects to analyze) and it end up with out of memory exception.
Any idea of how to unload the workspace/solution/project to free used memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `IWorkspace` that makes me believe that you're using a very, *very* old version of Roslyn. Make sure you're using the [current version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis) from NuGet, because we changed a *lot* since then. And fixed oh so many bugs.

In the current API, we got rid of the interface and `Workspace` implements `IDisposable`, so you can dispose it like any other disposable type by calling Dispose(). It's entirely possible the ancient version you're using also is disposable, but I honestly don't remember.

Comment: Yes I was using an old version of Roslyn. With the latest version every works fine. By calling `Workspace.Dispose`, the memory stops growing up. Thanks a lot.